# What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143(Java)? What could be my mistake?

Tags: java, primes, long-integer

The code works just fine for the int data type, but 600851475143 seems to be too big of a number. How can I make it work? It just keeps running and never gives me an answer.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       long a = 600851475143L;
        boolean prime = false;
        long big = 0L;
        for (long i = 1L; i < a; i++){
            if (a % i == 0){
                for (int j = 2; j < i/(float)2; j++){
                    if (i % j == 0){
                        prime = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(!prime){
                    big = i;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(big);
    }
}
```

Comment: put this `if (i % 1000_000 == 0) System.out.println(i);` at the top of your `for` loop

Comment: `break;` also only breaks out of the current `for`  and as `prime` is not being reset, it seems to be doing nothing.

Comment: This is Project Euler problem #3.  If you search on that you should find some help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `long` also for `j`.

Your variable naming is also a bit misleading: `prime` is true when the number is not a prime ...

Comment: This looks like a helpful comment.... but not like an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a lot of problems. My first advice would be to write clean and concise code with well-named variables. Secondly, analyze the runtime complexity of your program even if it works fast for large inputs. The fact that you run an inner loop inside `if(a % i == 0)` condition, makes your program extremely inefficient.

Here I provide a refactored version of your code with runtime complexity and good variable names in mind:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(largestPrimeFactorOf(600851475143L));
  }

  public static long largestPrimeFactorOf(long input)
  {
    List<Long> factors = new ArrayList<>();
    // You start from 2, as 1 is not a prime number and also using 1 will cause an infinite loop
    for (long i = 2L; i < input; i++) {
      if (input % i == 0) {
        factors.add(i);
        while (input % i == 0) {
          input /= i;
        }
      }
    }

    // As we always add a bigger number to the factor list, the last element is the greatest factor.
    return factors.get(factors.size() - 1);
  }
```

**Denote that this program will still be slow when the input is a large prime number, e.g. 100000000019. To handle such cases efficiently, it's better to use an efficient primality test algorithm. You can search the web for that.**
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test

Comment: Helpful. Most of my code is inefficient, I pretty much just started in January, but this website seems like a great resource to help fix that. I just tried solving the problem with the Java I've learned so far, so some of the code you use is new and not yet understandable to me.

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but what does this part of the code do?  List<Long> factors = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: The code `List<Long> factors = new ArrayList<>();` will initialize `factors` with an empty `List`. There are lots of good tutorials about Java's Generics and Collections for details.